# How do I add a forwarding rule in UFW?

Tags: ufw, dnsmasq

I have set up an Ubuntu server with 2 network cards as a basic router using `dnsmasq` as the DNS and DHCP server and I'm using `ufw` to control `iptables`.

Everything works and I think I have a pretty good basic understanding of what is going on.

However, in order to forward packets I have to set `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"` in `/etc/default/ufw`. The config file states that I probably also want to adjust my rules.

I adjusted `/etc/ufw/before.rules` and added:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
```

So my question is:

Is it bad to set the default to "ACCEPT"? Can I not just leave the default policy as "DROP" and add a forward rule with UFW?

I added a forward rule but it didn't actually forward packets.

```
sudo ufw route allow in on enp0s8 out on enp0s3 to 0.0.0.0/24 from 192.168.0.0/24
```

Comment: See also https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ufw-and-iptables-issue-with-port-forwarding

Comment: Already read the port forwarding link, i ll read the digital ocean one now.

Answer (score 2):

Well I have several comments:

1. You MUST "ACCEPT" as per "set DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT" in order to forward traffic between your 2 network cards. If you used iptables, rather than UFW you could write more specific rules if you so desired.
2. What do you mean by default to "ACCEPT" ? If by default you accept all traffic this is the same as not running a firewall. You could simply disable your firewall.

Setting the default policy to REJECT will lock yourself out if you flush your rules.

IMO best to keep default as ACCEPT, write all your rules for what to accept, and then have REJECT as the final rule in iptables. This way you will not be locked out if you flush the rules.

3. Don't use DROP, use REJECT - See  http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject
4. We really can not tell you what rules to use or how to write them without more information.

What servers are you running ? What traffic do you want to forward ? What are your current rules ?

IMO if you are writing extensive and complex rules sometimes it is easier to use iptables rater than UFW.

Comment: Its actually an academic excercise to learn more about networking. Specifically I am using ubuntu server as dns server, dhcp server and internet gateway hence the routing. My comment about ACCEPT refers only to the default forward policy in order to route traffic from one interace to the other, have I actually accepted all traffic on all interfaces ? Hmmm didnt realise that.

Comment: Let me phrase the question another way. I have enabled forwarding as shown above, then set a rule in the ufw before.rules to forward traffic from lan to wan using masquerade, then used ufw to allow all outgoing and reject all incoming. In essence have I done this correctly ?

Comment: Been doing more reading and it seems dnsmasq itself has the ability to set the default route to that of the main router. Maybe dnsmasq is all I need here and I dont need to configure iptables (or ufw) myself to forward traffic. I will have a play tomorrow.